# Trouble with nginx rewrite

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting

Hi so I need to rewrite this:

```
www.site.com/foo.php?var1=value1&var2=value2
```

to this:

```
www.site.com/value2
```

I tried this:

```
location /value2 {
  rewrite ^/value2/?$ /foo.php?var1=value1&var2=value2;
}
```

And this variant seemed to work but the point is that variables didn't pass...

and this:

```
location /foo.php {
if ($arg_var2 ~ "value2") {
        rewrite ^ http://site.com/$arg_var2? permanent;
    }
}
```

But it didn't work... Any ideas? Thanks in advance

Comment: The question isn't clear to me. It says rewrite to "/const2". but you tried to rewrite from "/const2"? Also what's the actual output of your failed test?

Comment: The point is that the variables don't pass.

Comment: is the const2 in www.site.com/foo.php?var1=const1&var2=const2 the same as in www.site.com/const2 ? If it is a constant, why do you make it a variable ?

Answer (score 0):

if value1 and value2 are constant, you can use :

```
    if ($args ~ "var1=value1&var2=value2") {
          set $args / ;
          rewrite ^.*$  /const2 permanent;
    }
```

another solution is something more flexible, which shoul work with other values, but that I didn't manage to make work with regex (this one doesn't work but it shouldn't be too far):

```
location / {
    rewrite ^/foo.php.*var2=.*$ /$2 redirect;   
}
```

Comment: Ok, but in what location should I use the first solution?